# Live Agent: issue with startChat

Tags: javascript, liveagent

I am trying to create a very simple Live Agent deployment page, with the link *always* being displayed (we handle no agent being available in the pre-chat page).  Here's the code I put together.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
      Thank you for contacting customer support. 
      <p/>
    <a id="liveagent_button_online_573q000000000Ig" href="javascript://Chat" onclick="liveagent.startChat('573q000000000Ig')">Start Chat</a>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la3-c1cs-was.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/36.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
liveagent.init('https://d.la3-c1cs-was.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572q000000000Bu', '00Dq00000000VFQ');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens, and I see the following error in the JS Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startChat' of undefined (deployment.js:68)

Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Notice that you are using "button_online", which only works when an agent is online.

Comment: Rob, thanks for your comment.  But that is nothing more than the id of the link element, removing that made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out, I had to add "liveagent.showWhenOnline" to window._laq, but not "liveagent.showWhenOffline".  Here is the working code if anyone is interested:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
      Thank you for contacting customer support. 
      <p/>
    <a  href="javascript://Chat" onclick="liveagent.startChat('573q000000000Ig')">Start Chat</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('573q000000000Ig', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_573q000000000Ig')); });
</script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la3-c1cs-was.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/36.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
liveagent.addCustomDetail('spacename', '%placeId%'); 
liveagent.addCustomDetail('ctype', '%cust_type%'); 
liveagent.addCustomDetail('orgid', '%orgid%'); 
liveagent.init('https://d.la3-c1cs-was.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572q000000000Bu', '00Dq00000000VFQ');
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time I got that error was because the method

```
liveagent.showWhenOnline('YOUR_ID_HERE', document.getElementById('your_element'));
```

was using one ID and then, the

```
onclick="liveagent.startChat('YOUR_ID_HERE')"
```

was using a different ID. Try to make sure you have the same ID on both places.

And make sure you check if the Button Id is online or not using *showWhenOnline*, otherwise *Deployment.js* won't able to open the chat.